# asp.net mvc database first .cs files not generated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ms-access, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have an existing Access database and need to build a REST api. The best way I thought is to migrate it to SQL server and build an asp.net mvc web api. But I'm a complete noob in EF... I tried database first following [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-models-and-data-access). But EF didn't seem to generate any .cs classes..or .tt files.

[image: Model folder]

The only file I got is .designer.cs.

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Have you added ADO.NET Entity DataModel? with connections?

Comment: I think so, that's where I got .designer.cs from, right.

Comment: haven't you got any *.edmx.diagram?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I'm such a n00b.. I selected ADO.NET EntityObject Generator instead of EF 5.x DbContext Geneerator.. thanks..

Comment: No Problem, 
mistakes are good for learning.